# select a single appended input with jquery

Tags: jquery, append, jquery-selectors

i have a row of inputs that are dynamically appended from a button. the first input is connected to a `<datalist>` that is populated by php from the database. when i click one of these items from the list, it pulls the price information for that specific item and i need it to automatically populate the next input with that price. i can `alert("value.price");` just fine, but cannot think of a way to select only the corresponding `<input>`. if i use `.class`, it will select ALL of the dynamically generated inputs with that class and will change the price of all items to that price. obviously, i only want the one input in that one row to change. i am able to do that with my delete script by using `closest` but that is not applicable when it comes to the `<input>` within the row.

here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#new_line_btn').click(function() {
    $('#pricing').append('<div class = "row"><div class = "col-sm input_col"><input name = "part_input[]" class ="form-control part_class" list = "part_list"></div>'
      +
      '<div class = "col-sm"><div class = "input-group"><span class = "input-group-text">$</span><input class = "form-control price_class" name = "price[]" onchange = "this.value = Number (this.value).toFixed(2)"></div>'
      +
      '</div><div class = "col-sm"><div class = "input-group"><input class = "form-control"><button class = "btn btn-light btn-outline-secondary delete">x</button></div></div></div>');
  });

  $('#pricing').on("change", ":focus", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var part_id = $('#part_list [value="' + value + '"]').data('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'invoice_array.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        part_id: part_id
      },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data) {
        alert(value.price);
      }
    })
  });

  $("#pricing").on("click", ".delete", function() {
    $(this).closest("div[class = 'row']").remove();
  });
});
```

as you can see i am appending a row with bootstrap columns and a delete button for that row. but how do i select ONLY the input with `class = "price_class"` and ONLY for that particular row?

this:

```
<input class = "form-control price_class" name = "price[]" onchange = "this.value = Number (this.value).toFixed(2)">
```

is where i need the price to appear.

the inputs are not direct siblings and the only other questions i see on similar topics are about `.on()` and selecting after dynamic element creation, which is not my problem.

in the code snip i have:

```
success: function(data){                             
        alert(value.price);                                 
}
```

but it should be something closer to:

```
    success: function(data){                                
        $('.price_class').val(value.price);                                 
    }
```

how do i select ONLY the price input for that dynamically created row?
thank you

Comment: Why do you think you can't use `$(this).closest(".row")` in the `change` method.

Comment: Shouldn't the selector for the `change` event be more specific, like `.price_class`?

Comment: The `change` event only happens on the input that's focused.

Comment: There are multiple inputs that could be focused, but your event handler assumes that when it changes it's the price.

Comment: you are correct. i've filtered it further to: `input[name='part_input[]']:focus`. thank you for your help. you really deserve the credit for this solution. and to anyone copy/pasting this code in the future: its `(data.price)` not `(value.price)` fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you could access it in a similar way, just specify you want to target the last matching input.

```
 $('#pricing').on("change", ":focus", function() {
    let _this = $(this)
    // ....
    success: function(data) {
      _this.closest('.row').find('input').last().val(data.price);
    }
```

Comment: @Barmar, look carefully at answer. he defined it as a var first.

Comment: @bungee1980 He did that after my comment.

Comment: thank you Kinglish, technically I had to use `eq(1)` instead of `.last` but this was the right idea!